# Uploaded csv file encoded in UTF-8 has triangle question mark letters (czech letters) after getting content

Tags: php

I have an issue with csv file which is encoded (probably) in UTF-8. The problem is that this csv file contains triangle question mark letters like on the screen [image: wrong letters].

When I open this file in PHPStorm it suggests me to change the encoding to windows-1250 and then the letters are displayed properly. The problem is that I have to handle this file on the backend because it will be uploaded.

I've tried:

- reading the file by file_get_contents then changing encoding via `iconv('Windows-1250', "utf-8", $content);` and checking content, then saving the file again but the letters are still strange like on this screenshot (strange d'ż letters instead of á) [image: screenshot]
- using `mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');`with different output and input encodings

Comment: Maybe the encoding suggested by phpstorm is not the right one?

Comment: @yolenoyer I've written this thing about PHPStorm because it's the only program which handles this file and reads it properly. For example when I import this file in excel and try with each encoding none of them is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (of course you can modify as needed, this script rewrites the original file)

```
function changeEncoding($filePath, $in, $out)
{
    $fileopen = file_get_contents($filePath);
    file_put_contents($filePath, iconv($in, $out, $fileopen));
}
```